# Modifying default behavior of outlook buttons

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-addins

Is it possible to modify the behavior of existing buttons in outlook (or generally in ms office programs)? E.g. can I make the "send mail" button show a dialog before sending a mail?

I know that you can make add ins and put them into ribbon but can you add certain behavior to existing controls?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` und handle the `Send` event. You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia).
You have use your application reference to get the active `inspector` and by the active `inspector` you retrieve the message class:

```
(CType(inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)).Send += New Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(Inspector_Send)

Private Sub Inspector_Send(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
... your code...
End Sub
```

Comment: Better than that, you can use Application.ItemSend event - you won't have to track open inspectors, plus a message can be sent as an inline reply without opening an inspector.